# array element as linkedlist in java

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have an home work,I used an array and element of array is linked list because the element in a row is not fixed need delete or add some time depend on problem condition , I was tried these codes below, but I have a problem when adding new element to a fixed row for example p[0] the value will be added for all, how I can solve this problem please help.

```
public class schedule
{
   public class link
   {
     public LinkedList <Integer>list = new LinkedList<Integer>() ;
     public link(LinkedList<Integer> value)
    {
        list = value;
    }
    public link(int value)
    {
        list.add(Integer.valueOf(value)) ;
    }

}


private link p[] = new link[10];
public schedule()
{
    LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    l.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
    l.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
    l.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
    for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++)
        p[j] = new link(l);



    p[0].list.add(9); // here I  have problem

    for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print("p["+j+"]:");
        for(int i=0;i<p[j].list.size();i++)
            System.out.print(p[j].list.get(i).intValue());
        System.out.println();
    }

}
public static void main(String []arg)
{
    new schedule();
}


the output is like this : the value 9 added to all but I want to be added just for first element
p[0]:2039
p[1]:2039
p[2]:2039
p[3]:2039
p[4]:2039
p[5]:2039
p[6]:2039
p[7]:2039
p[8]:2039
p[9]:2039
```

Comment: Please try and word your question more specifically. I don't really understand what you saying.

Comment: What problem are you facing?? And please re-phrase your question properly..

Comment: OP has stated the problem in the comment. Just check the code above the *problematic* sentence to understand.

Comment: Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're initializing every `link` instance with the same `LinkedList<Integer>`:

```
LinkedList<Integer> l = new LinkedList<Integer>();
l.add(Integer.valueOf(2));
l.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
l.add(Integer.valueOf(3));
for(int j=0;j<p.length;j++)
//it will be the same LinkedList<Integer> l per all the instances in the array
    p[j] = new link(l);
```

Take note that when you do this, every `link` instance will have the `list` attribute referencing the same `LinkedList<Integer> l` variable. So, if you modify it in one place, everyone will be *updated* (because it's the same reference).

There are many ways to solve this:

- Create a new LinkedList on every iteration of your for loop.
- Create the new `link` instance using another constructor.
- Fill your `link[] p` array one by one...

Comment: I used new link constructor for add just an element but it will erase the existing element, and add add just new one.

Comment: @AKWARD You should understand what the code is doing. For these cases, you should use a debugger and maybe some `System.out.println(...);` lines in the code to see the behavior of the variables. Note that your `link` class has a `LinkedList<Integer>` constructor that is replacing the value of the `LinkedList <Integer>list` attribute.

Comment: yes it is now working I was create new linkedlist for every iteration , thanks

Comment: @AKWARD don't forget to mark the post as an answer by clicking the check next to the post :).